# SQL Server Connection Issue - I can connect but other users can't

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

[edit] so not sure what happened, but we ended up resetting the server and turning off/on TCP/IP and Named Pipes and after a restart and updating the settings everything started working again. weirdest thing. anyways thanks for the help guys.

I'm building a C# WPF application for my job, and I'm getting a weird problem that I've been trying to figure out for the past week. The application connects to the server and imports several tables on start up. So I built it out and was testing it with no issues, but when i pass it to our testers, and everyone is getting the following errors:

> Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server

The users are able to connect to the server through other methods (SSMS/Excel VBA), but just through the application it won't work.

I've checked the following:

1. Remote connections enabled
2. TCP/IP connections enabled
3. Firewall settings are the exact same across all users (me included)
4. application is compiled as 32 bit (saw this in another thread)

We're using SQL Server 2008 and I've tried several connection strings/methods.

below is the code I'm using to connect:

```
 public void Open_DB_Conn(string Connection_Str)
 {
        try
        {
            Sql_Conn = new SqlConnection(Conn_Str);
            Sql_Conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Error Message:{0} Conn String: {1}",e.Message,Conn_Str));
        }
    }
```

Below is my connection string (this is just one of many iterations I've used trying to get it working):

```
Data Source=IP Address;Initial Catalog=DB_Name;User ID=LOGIN;Password=PWD
```

Anyone know why I would be the only one able to get it to work and that the users are able to login to the server using other applications without a problem? They use it for logging their excel VBA scripts and there aren't any issues there.

Comment: common case is that your TCP port isn't properly configured

Comment: Are they connecting from the same network?

Comment: yep same network. i'll have them look over the TCP port, thoughts on what they should look for? (i'm not the server admin and am not familiar with it.

Comment: Make sure that TCP is enabled on the *client* as well as the server.

Comment: ahhh ok i'll check that. Would they still be able to connect via other applications if it wasn't? they're able to connect via VBA and SSMS

Comment: In your connection strings you've tried have you tried forcing it to tcp instead of named pipes? `DataSource=tcp:<host name>,<TCP/IP port number>`?

Comment: Did you check all 10 steps mentioned in http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/?

Comment: @JamesBarrass - Yes i've tried that and indicating "tcp:<ip address>" as well. 

L-Three - yep we've tried each of those steps as well. we're stymied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this - it may be your answer

"The error is reported by client library. While your server is listeing on remote TCP, client will still try TCP and NP connection in order. So the error client behavior is expected. From what you have described, I believe that even though you enabled the remote TCP connection on the XPSP2 machine, you didn't make the TCP listening port an exception of XPSP2 personal firewall. You should follow steps below to resolve this issue.

1. check the SQL Server Errorlog to make sure SQL Server is now listening on TCP/IP and confirm which port it is listening on.  Usually 1433.  In the Errorlog, you will see several lines that discuss what SQL Server is listening on. Below is an example:

   2006-01-04 01:41:07.65 server    SQL server listening on 10.254.1.150: 1433.     <--Shows the IP Address and the port.

   2006-01-04 01:41:07.65 server    SQL server listening on 127.0.0.1: 1433.          <--Shows another IP Address and the port.

   2006-01-04 01:41:07.69 server    SQL server listening on TCP, Shared Memory, Named Pipes.

   2006-01-04 01:41:07.69 server    SQL Server is ready for client connections

2, Make sure on Windows XP that the firewall is not blocking that port.

3, go to your client machine and run the client network configuration tool (cliconfg.exe)  Make sure TCP/IP is enabled, click properties and make sure the port number is the same one as SQL Server is listening on. Here you can enable NP or disable client NP as well.

Once both the client and the server are using TCP/IP with the same port number and the firewall on server machines is not blocked, you should be able to connect.

Hope this helps."

(Ref: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c488cf76-2515-440f-b3f8-9cfad689c5b6/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server?forum=sqldataaccess)

Answer (score 0):

You have to configured your SQl server so that other IP can connect it for that you have to gone through mentioned link

[Configure SQL server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190780/SQL-Server-2008-R2-Setup-Configurations-Remote-Acc)

Comment: Yes it has been setup for remote connections, and we've been able to use it in other applications

Answer (score 0):

What authentication are you using for the SQL Server? Windows Authentication or SQL Server authentication? My suggestion is to first turn on SQL Server authentication and use the sa\password to connect to the server. If you are successful, then ask the others (users of your application) to try with the same connection string. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: SQL Server Auth - they're all using the same username/password that i am using. i even tried logging into other computers to see if it had to do with my computer.

Comment: So you are saying that you can connect to that database using only your machine? That doesn't sound right. Can you use Management Studio on their machine and get to the database (log in on the machine as that user).

Comment: Yes they can connect via other methods (as stated in the problem), and i agree it doesn't sound right. i've never heard of this happening, and i can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you check if your Server has all of these configured? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: Also, do the other users have a different operating system than you do?

Comment: Try this - it may be your answer

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the port specified in:

```
Data Source="IPAddress,port";Initial Catalog=DB_Name;User ID=LOGIN;Password=PWD
```

matches the port on your SQL Server. You can check that by going on SQL Server COnfiguration Manager and viewing TCP/IP properties.

**EDIT :**

It is also the case the port defined by blocked by an external firewall. And the rest Applications use other ports. Try to find out which port you can use (if indeed the are restrictions to your network)

Comment: Yea i tried that as well, i tried: 

"IP, Port"
"IP"
"servername"

and trying to connect via ADODB, ODBC

Comment: I've also checked the firewall settings and they're the exact same on all computers (mine included). I believe the port is 1433 (sql server port), would there be another one used by the application that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your SQL Server instance is properly configured to use TCP using Sql Server Configuration Manager.

It is by default disabled in SQL Express, as show below.

[image]

Comment: You checked the firewall? Maybe a deny rule are overriding your allow rule, try using telnet in the SQL Server port.

Is the database in the single user mode? Using SQL Server Management Studio the database icon will appear differently (if I remember the word single should appear somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to know more about your "Sql_Conn" class.

Also, try using this for your connection.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        string cmdText = "SELECT name FROM sys.tables"


        cmd.CommandText = cmdText;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```